# Apache2 and SSH. Both on port same IP and port

Tags: apache, ssh, tunnel

My question may be a little confusing, but anyway. My school is going to open up WiFi DMZ on separate IP for students, but they said port 80 will be the only port open.

What do I want? Well I want to tunnel my traffic thru my home server, which is running Apache2 on 80 and SSH on 21. It's just a regular setup. As it is a production machine and I want clients to be able to connect on port 80, but I want to connect to port 80 to make a tunnel. The question is: How to do that?

The possible sollution: Abandon possibility of connecting to websites running on the server from the school IP and use IPTABLES. If source ip == $school_ip && port == 80: Redirect to port 21. Done. But I think there must another, elegant sollution... Isn't it possible to actually use the HTTP transfer for SSH transit? I mean create a host named for example ssh.mydomain.tld and use some apache module to do a server-side redirection to port 21 but only on that particular hostname? What can I do?

Box is running Debian GNU/Linux

### Thanks for any help...

Off topic: They think they will block any sort of illegal operation. In fact HTTP is probably the second most-vulnerable protocol after BitTorrent. Why don't lock it down too? It'll be absolutely safe if there's no open ports, wouldn't it? I don't personally think blocking ports for POP, IMAP, Jabber, etc is any good. I think they'll probably seriously piss someone off if they even can't open mail teacher sent them. Oh, there's a webmail? No no no! SSL/TLS goes on port 443, remember? I don't think blocking all the traffic will be any good. IMO they should block unencrypted BitTorrent and apply low-priority QoS for unclassified transfers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the instructions found here:
http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/

proxytunnel is available in the stable repo:
http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=proxytunnel&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

Comment: Okay, I'll take a snapshot of the VM and take a look at it... Will report my success back. Thanks!

Comment: You bet! Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Well the tutorial on the web you post is working for the part of setting up apache2. The connecting is correct on http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/techniques/firewall.html though. Anyway, solved the problem. Will test in real environment once the "gods" themselves opens the "great opportunities of the port 80". I will probably gonna find a way for tunnelling non-socks compliant application. If nothing else, VPN server on the server could do the trick... Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple and working solution is [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml).
It is exactly the tool to solve that problem.
BTW ssh is usually set on port 22.